# javascript processing

Tags: javascript, optimization, resources

Is there a way to check the resource usage with a javascript code?
Can i check RAM usage and cpu usage of the script?

Since there are various ways to do something, i might write the code using different methods, and save it in as 2 different files, and check which method is more optimized. Esp when i'm calling a function recursively.
This way, i'll get to learn which methods are better and what to use.

Anything like maybe an addon, or maybe a script to be added that does this. It would be much better if it shows function wise. I'm not sure if something like this exists.

On a note, with chrome inspector, i tried CPU profiling, but it seems to show me values according to time, and does not show the RAM/CPU usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no uniform cross-browser way to do this. You can get an overall sense of your javascript performance by using Chrome's *Timeline* tool. Switch between the *Timelines* and *Memory* tabs on the left and hit the record button at the bottom. I believe Safari has a similar tool.

Internet Explorer has the excellent [DynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) tool, although I don't know it well enough to provide detailed instruction on how to use it.

Note that javascript interpreters vary wildly in implementation, so they may have very different performance characteristics. Rather than get caught up in the details of implementation (premature optimization is evil and all that), write your code with good coding practices in mind. That means that if you do have performance bottlenecks (which the profiling tools available will help you locate), you can refactor more readily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any specific way to test the Ram and CPU stats of javascript. But I often user http://jsperf.com/ to see how two different functions perform.

Comment: Thanks for that link, will try out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Crome `Tools > Task Manager` in **Chome Tools** menu options? It shows the CPU and Memory Usage for each process running in the borwser (comprise `chrome-extension`s).

Comment: Yes, I checked that, but it's more often for checking extensions. It lists processing/ram usage of the whole page and not the program. There is one way of making each function on a separate page, and then checking, but that's just like opening a the pages in different browser windows and recording stats by the OS.